# Exibir um ALERT e redirecionar a página

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma página aonde está o formulário com um action que envia as informações do formulário para uma outra página.

Gostaria que, após inserido o registro, fosse exibida uma mensagem de confirmação (ou negação) e que, após clicar no botão OK, houvesse um redirecionamento para a página original.

Na página do formulário está assim:

```
<form id="frmCad" name="frmCad" method="post" action="../inc/processa.php?modo=incluir&fnc=<?php echo $fnc; ?>&ans=<?php echo $linha; ?>">
```

O arquivo proxessa.php está assim:

```
$fnc        = $_GET['fnc'];
$linha      = $_GET['ans'];

if($modo == "incluir"){

$sql = "INSERT INTO `pe_premorc` (etc)

$linhafec       = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);
if($linhafec == 1){
    echo "<script>alert('Premissa incluída com sucesso');</script>";
    header('Location: ../views/premorc.php?fnc=$fnc&ans=$linha');
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Ocorreu um erro. A premissa não foi incluída');</script>";
    header('Location: ../views/premorc.php?fnc=$fnc&ans=$linha');
}
```

Porém não estou conseguindo o efeito desejado. Ou exibe a mensagem e fica na mesma página, ou nem exibe a mensagem e redireciona com os parâmetros errados, tipo http://localhost/final/views/premorc.php?fnc=$fnc&ans=$linha

Comment: Venho dizer que testei a primeira e, essa deu certo, funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente desta forma, colocando o redirecionamento no javascript também:

```
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Ocorreu um erro. A premissa não foi incluída')
window.location.href='../views/premorc.php?fnc=$fnc&ans=$linha';
</SCRIPT>");
```

Exemplo:

```
$fnc        = $_GET['fnc'];
$linha      = $_GET['ans'];

if($modo == "incluir"){

$sql = "INSERT INTO `pe_premorc` (etc)"

$linhafec       = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);
if($linhafec == 1){
    echo ("<script>
        window.alert('Premissa incluída com sucesso')
        window.location.href='../views/premorc.php?fnc=$fnc&ans=$linha';
    </script>");
} else {
    echo ("<script>
        window.alert('Ocorreu um erro. A premissa não foi incluída')
        window.location.href='../views/premorc.php?fnc=$fnc&ans=$linha';
    </script>");
}
```

Você pode fazer desta forma também:

Enviar a mensagem como parâmetro:

```
$mensagem = 'Ocorreu um erro. A premissa não foi incluída';
header("Location: ../views/premorc.php?fnc=$fnc&ans=$linha&msg=$mensagem");
```

e na pagina premorc.php mostra a mensagem:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
    echo "<script>alert('" . $_GET['msg'] . "');</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Wictor, mas está retornando o erro 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in D:\xampp\htdocs\final\inc\processa.php on line 41 que é aonde está o window.location =

Comment: Coloquei uma nova forma de fazer veja.

Comment: E alterei também o primeiro para corrigir este erro